# the different between ANACONDA environment and ATOM

Tags: python, anaconda, atom-editor

I take some online courses on `Udemy` and one of the instructors use `Anaconda` and `Jupiter` notebook, another one use `Atom`.

I have no programming background so please explain to me the commons and differences between them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is a way to distribute Python, where Jupyter and Atom are ways to interact with a python interpreter. Atom is a traditional text editor used to just write python code, and Jupyter is a lot more complicated, it's more of a toolkit revolving around math, science, and big data, and allows you to write/run python/julia/r/scala/etc scripts.